# how to minify bootstrap by gulp, installed by bower and move fonts to dist?

Tags: less, gulp, bower

I have this situation. I want to concat and copy all css and js files installed by bower to /dist/:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var bower       = require('main-bower-files');
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(bower({ paths: 'app' }), { read: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  ;
});

/app
---/bower_components/
------/bootstrap/
------/jquery/
------/etc/
/dist
gulpfile.js
```

bower(...) returns the list of files to work on:

```
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less',
'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```

The problem is that bootstrap has .less instead of .css files.

1. How do I run lessc inside the gulp file?
2. And how do I copy font files as well? (very important as well).

P.S. I don't want to modify bower components in any way because it defeats bower upgrade.
P.P.S. I don't want to write custom logic for bootstrap either. I want to treat all bower components equally to process all css, js, sass, less, copy fonts and images to /dist/ automatically.

Comment: Voting to close this since the Q shows the lack of doing even a trivial search and documentation reading.

Comment: @seven-phases-max unfortunately it seems like SO is turning into that, in some cases basic orientation is sometimes unwelcome and the user desires a step by step process to solve their issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Gulp-Less library has an example with options:

https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less

There is also a Gulp-Copy library that you can use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy

Comment: don't think gulp-copy will help to copy the fonts, because the fonts are speified inside less file. And there is no link inside bower.js. So it is the lessc compiler who should be aware of the links to fonts and images, and be able to identify them.

Comment: @user3235751 Less compiler of course can't and shouldn't copy any font or image or whatever linked files for you. Instead you copy them yourself (for example using `gulp-copy`) to wherever you need and for Less you simply specify where the links in the resulting CSS should point to (for [example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-variables-icons)).

Comment: the problem is, if I change @icon-font-path which is inside bower_components, then other developers in my project who have to install the components from scratch, will not have that icon-path modified and will have difficulties. And as far as I understand I shouldn't commit bower_components into the repo as it is a bad practice.

Comment: Also by using gulp-copy -- I could copy the files by myself, but in this case I have to write it for each component (bootstrap, font-awesome, tinymce, etc). Why, if there is a bower.js in each component. Isn't there an automated way to copy everything?